# Android ListView with ArrayAdapter and background service does not keep the items in the correct order

Tags: android, listview

When I render / update the list view after the service get's new data the order of the list items is changing every time.

The ArrayAdapter has an ArrayList member and all the items are in correct order until shown on the screen. I also have two ItemViewTypes, one for the header of the items and one for the items of course. This is rendered with the ViewHolder "pattern".

I guess I'm missing something silly.

What could cause such behavior?

Comment: lol, yeah my implementation could have been an issue, but like I said.. the order of the items is in order all the way.. until it reaches the List. Will create a sample app later to demonstrate what is happening. Can't show current code..

Comment: most important is getItemViewType and getView. headers and items are in the same ArrayList ? ... it'sreally hard to answer without code and i don't know, maybe print screen of this behavior

Comment: Some code here : https://gist.github.com/1308835

Comment: you don't need support items type if you're infalting from the same layout delete getItemViewType and change getView to http://pastebin.com/VGkr2f7U ... in your code you didn't set values if convertView != null :)

Comment: my bad .. i missed that *you're using different layouts* ... so try this http://pastebin.com/zi29LLUh

Comment: Just merged the layouts into 1 and with your code it's working!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that **`ArrayAdapter`** holds it's own **shallow copy** of the **List** you provide on instantiation of the `ArrayAdapter`. If this assumption holds true, the consequence is that modifications of list items are shown by the ListView while modifications of the list item order will not be reflected.

If your **list items are comparable** so that the required order can be recovered, you could call the `ArrayAdapter.sort(Comparator comp)` method and the ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method afterwards. In my case even the **scroll position** was **preserved perfectly**.

However, you could also try to use the `add` and `remove` methods of `ArrayAdapter` to update the adapter itself.